# Help Test Class for custom webservice

Tags: apex, unit-test, soap-api, webservices, soap

Below is my code which class is call from php may i know how can i test my webservice
for code coverage

```
global class SpecialAccounts {

  global class AccountInfo {
     webService String AcctName;
     webService Integer AcctNumber;
  }

  webService static Account createAccount(AccountInfo info) {
    Account acct = new Account();
    acct.Name = info.AcctName;
    acct.AccountNumber = String.valueOf(info.AcctNumber);
    insert acct;
    return acct;
  }

        Id [] results = new Id[3];
        results[0] = parent.Id;
        results[1] = child.Id;
        results[2] = grandChild.Id;
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call your static class in test class with proper data

```
List<Main.AccountWrapper> lstmainwrap=new List<Main.AccountWrapper>();
integer i;
 for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
    Main.AccountWrapper accwarp=new Main.AccountWrapper();
    accwarp.accName='testacc'+i;
    accwarp.accNumber=i;
    lstmainwrap.add(accwarp);
 }

Main.RequestClass req=new Main.RequestClass();
req.accounts=lstmainwrap;

Test.startTest();
  Main.ResponseClass RES=Main.behaviourOfWebService(req);
Test.stopTest();
```

//Assert the behaviour as expected

Comment: when i use your test class records are not inserting in sfdc.May i know why it happens.

Comment: test.startTest() and stoptest it showing an error method does not exist.

Comment: post what ave you tried .This was a sample code ,so post your code so far.

Comment: i post my code in answer coloumn once check it.

Comment: Again records are not inserting i think we miss the insert statement.Could you modify my code.

Comment: For Me Again Data is not inserting into sfdc, May i know how can i change my code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hosting the webservices inside Salesforce, it shouldn't be very difficult to test them. Just call the methods of the webservice class like they are some normal methods and test/assert the outcome.

For instance you can call your "behaviourOfWebService" method by just doing

```
Main.behaviourOfWebService(new Main.RequestClass());
//plz send some actuall data instead of just "new Main.RequestClass()"
```

Have a look at the below links to read more about how to write test classes

- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_example.htm
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_test.htm
- http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: Can you give some sample code..

Comment: @Sathya I gave you the line to invoke the webservice method. It shouldnt be any different than writing test class for any other apex class

Comment: but it showing an error account name is not exist Main.behaviourOfWebService(new MainClass4.RequestClass());
     act.accName = 'Mytest';
     act.accNumber = '1238';
      Main.behaviourOfWebService( act );